# Store Multiple Order By Lamdas into List for later execution

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to store two different sorting expressions into list and then want to execute it using orderBy linq.

I have following code.

```
class Product 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name {get; set;}
}

List<?> GetSortExpressions() {
      Expression<Func<Product, int>> idSortExpression= p => p.Id;
      Expression<Func<Product, String>> nameSortExpression = p => p.Name;

      List<?> sorts = new List<?>();
      sorts.Add(idSortExpression);
      sorts.Add(nameSortExpression );
      return sorts;
}
```

Then I want to execute sorts list on  IQueryable object like below.

```
IQueryable<T> ApplySortExpressions(IQueryable<T> data, List<?> sorts) {
    for(int i=0;i < sorts.Count; i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            data = data.OrderBy(sorts[i]);
        } else {
            data = ((IOrderedQueryable<T>)data).ThenBy(sorts[i]);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

I can't add expressions to list because of type error. Can you please give me right list generic type for below line ?

```
List<?> sorts = new List<?>();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is not working ???

Comment: See updated question

Answer (score 0):

You could make the list of type "Expression" then you should be able to store both expressions in the same list, but  then you would have to cast the expressions back to their desired type in the ApplySortExpressions method otherwise you can't use them in the OrderBy or ThenBy method

Answer (score 0):

You can store them as `Expression<Func<Product, object>>>`. Then your functions become:

```
List<Expression<Func<Product, object>>> GetSortExpressions() {
    Expression<Func<Product, object>> idSortExpression = p => p.Id;
    Expression<Func<Product, object>> nameSortExpression = p => p.Name;

    var sorts = new List<Expression<Func<Product, object>>>();
    sorts.Add(idSortExpression);
    sorts.Add(nameSortExpression);
    return sorts;
}
```

and

```
IQueryable<T> ApplySortExpressions<T>(IQueryable<T> data, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> sorts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sorts.Count; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            data = data.OrderBy(sorts[i]);
        }
        else {
            data = ((IOrderedQueryable<T>) data).ThenBy(sorts[i]);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```